# Why @Validated + @Component + implement leads type misleading error in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, bean-validation

Here list of code samples:

**Base**

```
@Validated
@Component
public class MyImpl1 {}

@Validated
@Component
public class MyImpl2 {}

@Service
public MySelector {
    private final MyImpl1 myImpl1;
    private final MyImpl2 myImpl2;

    @Autowired
    public MySelector(MyImpl1 myImpl1, MyImpl2 myImpl2) {
        this.myImpl1 = myImpl1;
        this.myImpl2 = myImpl2;
    }

    public Object select (Long id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                return myImpl1;
            case 2:
                return myImpl1;
        }
    }
}
```

This **works**: beans are injected, no problem here. Important note here is `MyImpl` beans **are proxies** and this is **no
problem** for autowiring.

But things become different when I add `implements` like this:

**implements**

```
@Validated
@Component
public class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface{}

@Validated
@Component
public class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface{}

public interface MyInterface {}

@Service
public MySelector {
    private final MyImpl1 myImpl1;
    private final MyImpl2 myImpl2;

    @Autowired
    public MySelector(MyImpl1 myImpl1, MyImpl2 myImpl2) {
        this.myImpl1 = myImpl1;
        this.myImpl2 = myImpl2;
    }

    public Object select (Long id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                return myImpl1;
            case 2:
                return myImpl2;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I got:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'myImpl1' is expected to be of type 'MyImpl1' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108'
```

If I remove `@Validated` eve
ry become working again.

I understand that spring uses proxing and it is better to use interfaces. But I can not understand why I got problems here?
If spring **can** autowire a proxy by class name why it can not do this when `implements` added especially when this interface is not used in autowiring fields.

**UPDATED**

Spring-boot version is `2.0.3`
spring-core version is `5.0.7.RELEASE`

Comment: I cannot replicate this with Spring Boot 2.0.6 default settings. Which Spring Boot version do you have?

Comment: With interfaces JDK dynamic proxies (interface based) are use, else you are using class based proxies. Newer Spring Boot versions force always to use class based proxies. Either way it uses proxies but with interfaces it uses interface only proxies and else uses class based (CGLIB) proxies.

Comment: Works fine with Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With interfaces JDK dynamic proxies (interface based) are use, else
>   you are using class based proxies. Newer Spring Boot versions force
>   always to use class based proxies. Either way it uses proxies but with
>   interfaces it uses interface only proxies and else uses class based
>   (CGLIB) proxies.

From [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087873/why-validated-component-implement-leads-type-misleading-error-in-spring-bo#comment95008557_54087873).

This is true, adding interface leads to jdk proxy which is not a subclass from original class.

To force subclass proxy subclass add the following to bean declaration:

```
@Scope( proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
```

E.g.:

```
@Validated
@Component
@Scope( proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
public class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface{}
```